# Не запускается OpenServer

Tags: mysql

Не получается запустить OpenServer.

Выдает следующее:

```
2024-02-02 11:50:25  --------------------------------------------
2024-02-02 11:50:25  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
2024-02-02 11:50:25  Обновление Hosts файла
2024-02-02 11:50:25  Обновление конфигурации MySQL-5.6
2024-02-02 11:50:25  Обновление конфигурации Sendmail
2024-02-02 11:50:25  Обновление конфигурации PHP_7.2
2024-02-02 11:50:25  Обновление конфигурации PHPMyAdmin
2024-02-02 11:50:26  Обновление конфигурации Apache_2.4-PHP_5.5-5.6
2024-02-02 11:50:26  Запуск MySQL-5.6
2024-02-02 11:50:26  Запуск Apache_2.4-PHP_5.5-5.6
2024-02-02 11:50:26  Проверка состояния сервера
2024-02-02 11:50:42  Не удалось запустить Apache_2.4-PHP_5.5-5.6
2024-02-02 11:50:42  Сбой запуска!
2024-02-02 11:50:42  --------------------------------------------
2024-02-02 11:50:42  Начало процедуры остановки сервера
2024-02-02 11:50:42  Остановка системных модулей
2024-02-02 11:50:44  Отключение виртуального диска
2024-02-02 11:50:44  Сервер успешно остановлен за 1,342 секунд!
```

Что делать?

Comment: Посмотри логи во всех вкладках ,не только в "Основной"